# How to check if GetPropertyItem Exists in c#

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code

```
int OrientationId = 0x0112;
imgd.SetPropertyItem(imgs.GetPropertyItem(OrientationId));
```

in c# to grab a propertyitem from a image thats holding its orientation. However if this propertyitem doesn't exists it throws the following error "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code"

Therefore i figured i need some way to determine if this propertyItem exists before running this code. Any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's `imgd` and `imgs`?

Comment: IS the problem just that GetPropertyItem is returning null? If so can you not just put it into a local variable and check it before passing it into the Set?

Comment: It would be useful to add the message that the exception gives you in your question.

Comment: Asking for a non-existent property will throw an ArgumentException with the message 'Property cannot be found'

Comment: how about accepting one of the given answers?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linq you can simply do :

```
var propertyExists = image.PropertyItems.Any(p => p.Id == 0x0112);
```

Or, if you don't want to use Linq:

```
var propertyFound = false;
foreach (var prop in image.PropertyItems)
{
    if (prop.Id == 0x0112) propertyFound = true;
}
```

Comment: `bool propertyExists = img.PropertyIdList.Contains(0x0112);`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is an `Image`, you can use the [Image.PropertyIdList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyidlist(v=vs.110).aspx) and check if the id you want exists in that list.

Something like:

```
var ids = imgs.PropertyIdList;
if (ids.IndexOf(OrientationId) != -1) 
{
    imgd.SetPropertyItem(imgs.GetPropertyItem(OrientationId));
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Or retrieve all properties with `PropertyItems` then copy those actually needed

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `try catch`:

```
int OrientationId = 0x0112;
try
{  
    imgd.SetPropertyItem(imgs.GetPropertyItem(OrientationId));
}
catch(ArgumentException e)
{
    // Do whatever needs to be done
    Console.Log(e.Message);
}
```

By the way the `ArgumentException` seems to tell you that the error is not thrown by `GetPropertyItem` but `SetPropertyItem` with a `null` argument. One way to avoid that is:

```
int OrientationId = 0x0112;
PropertyItem p = imgs.GetPropertyItem(OrientationId);

if (p != null) imgd.SetPropertyItem(p);
```

Comment: ArgumentException is also thrown if the property can't be found. It's better to check what properties actually exist though than handle the exception

Comment: I think using `try catch` in a checking purpose is ALWAYS bad idea. Have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in another thread so i will copy it here as well since it worked the best for me

```
if (myImage.PropertyIdList.Any(p => p == 36867))
```

where myImage is an object of the the type Image